# DividerItemDecoration clipping shadows of RecyclerView list items

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I have a RecyclerView, and I'm using a DividerItemDecoration with the following xml layout to add padding between items.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <size
        android:width="16dp"
        android:height="96dp">
    </size>
</shape>
```

The list items themselves are CardViews within a LinearLayout, with no padding around the edges -- I want all of this to be provided by the divider. The problem I'm having is that the shadow behind the CardView is clipped at the edges rather than extending into the DividerItemDecoration. Is it possible to avoid this behaviour, so that the shadow does extend naturally into the gap? My instinct is no, but I feel like this must be a common use case. Or is there a better way to add spacing?